# Delete terraform output from state

Tags: terraform

How can I delete an output (that does not exist in code anymore)? It is not shown in `terraform state list` and I am therefore unable to target int with `tarraform state rm`. But I see it in the state file:

```bash
# terraform state pull | grep whatever -A2 -B100
{
  "version": 4,
  "terraform_version": "1.1.6",
  "serial": XXX,
  "lineage": "XXX",
  "outputs": {
    "stubborn": {
```

```bash
# terraform show | grep -B2 stubborn
Outputs:

stubborn = <<-EOT
<very VERY long text>
EOT
```

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: If you have the `output` resource in the code, Terraform will add it back to the state again when you run to apply the next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resorted to manual approach along the lines of:

```
terraform state pull > state-before.json
jq 'del(.outputs.stubborn)' state-before.json > state-after.json
# and increase serial or use --force
terraform state push state-after.json
```